# T method that can get nullable and notnullable variable

Tags: c#

I looking to create a method that can do the following thing:

```
string? s = xelement.GetValue < string > ( "elementname" );
Guid? g = xelement.GetValue < Guid > ( "elementname" );
int? i = xelement.GetValue < int > ( "elementname" );
DateTime? d = xelement.GetValue < DateTime > ( "elementname" );
```

is it possible?

Comment: No, you cannot have a `string?`.

Comment: why we have string.IsNullOrEmpty ?

Comment: String is a reference type and so it can have a null value already. Therefore, `Nullable<String>` wouldn't make sense as `Nullable<>` is designed to make `value types` nullable.

Comment: You can alter it so you call `.GetValue<Guid?>`, `GetValue<int?>` etc. Or have two different methods: one for structs and one for reference classes.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you will have to create 2 separate methods. In order to return `Nullable<T>`, you need the `struct` constraint, which prevents reference types from being used.

Comment: Isn't Nullable<T> in itself a type? So you could just create GetValue<T> where sometimes T is in fact sometimes Nullable<U>?

Answer (score 1):

Try this extension method will work with string, int and DateTime, because all these types are supported by `IConvertable` interface. Thus you can convert string to bool, byte, char, decimal, etc (except Guid):

```
public static T GetValue<T>(this XElement element, string name)
{
    string value = (string)element.Element(name);
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
}
```

BTW there is no `Nullable<string>` in C#, because nullable can accept only value types. So you should use simple string.

---

Usage:

```
<rooot>
  <string>hello</string>
  <int>42</int>
  <guid>0FFF30ED-0C4B-41ED-9CDA-D9E084FAD6F2</guid>
  <date>06/27/2013</date>
</rooot>
```

Parsing:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
XElement root = xdoc.Root;
string s = root.GetValue<string>("string");
int? i = root.GetValue<int>("int");
DateTime? d = root.GetValue<DateTime>("date");
```

If you want guids to be supported also, then you can manually parse them:

```
public static T GetValue<T>(this XElement element, string name)
{
    string value = (string)element.Element(name);    

    Type targetType =  typeof(T);
    if (targetType == typeof(Guid))
        return (T)(object)Guid.Parse(value);

    var typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(targetType);

    if (typeConverter == null || !typeConverter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)))
        return default(T); // or throw exception

    return (T)typeConverter.ConvertFrom(value);
}
```

---

**UPDATE** OK, if you want to return nullable value from method, then (remember, strings are not value types, so you can't parametrize method with `string`):

```
public static Nullable<T> GetValue<T>(this XElement element, string name)
    where T : struct
{
    string value = (string)element.Element(name);
    if (value == null)
        return null;

    Type targetType =  typeof(T);
    if (targetType == typeof(Guid))
        return (T)(object)Guid.Parse(value);

    var typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(targetType);

    if (typeConverter == null || !typeConverter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)))
        return null; // or throw exception

    return (T)typeConverter.ConvertFrom(value);
}
```

Comment: I must be missing something. Won't calling `GetValue<int>` _never_ return a `null` value? That is, isn't the usage that you have there simply returning an `int` and converting it to `int?` when assigned with `int? i = `?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair null value is not required. You can assign `int` to `int?` See method generic parameters - they are not nullable in question. Or maybe I'm missing something

Comment: My _impression_ was that Salvatore Di Fazio wanted to specify an `int` type and have it return `null` if the element wasn't found or some other exceptional case. That is, specify the underlying type `int` for `T` and have it return `T?`. EDIT: Of course, the actual _intent_ of what he's trying to do is not clear at all; it'd be nice to have better context as to what he's _wanting_ to do.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair OK, I understand your point. Updated answer with returning nullable types

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Null object" pattern. [Here](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/null_object)

Answer (score 0):

I tested this in LinqPad (my go-to quick C# sandbox) and it works:

```
    void Main()
{
    string s = GetValue<string>("elementname");
    Guid? g = GetValue<Guid?>("elementname");
    Guid h = GetValue<Guid>("elementname");
    int? i = GetValue<int?>("elementname");
    int j = GetValue<int>("elementname");
    DateTime? d = GetValue<DateTime?>("elementname");
    DateTime e = GetValue<DateTime>("elementname");

    Console.WriteLine(s);
    Console.WriteLine(g);
    Console.WriteLine(h);
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    Console.WriteLine(j);
    Console.WriteLine(d);
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}

T GetValue<T>(string elementName)
{
    return default(T);
}
```

Output:

```
null 
null 
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
null 
0
null 
1-1-0001 00:00:00
```